# Como pego o nome da classe num contexto estático?

Tags: java

eu quero pegar o nome da classe que chamou meu método

```
class A {
    public static String getClass(){
       return getCalledClass(); /*Supondo que exista esse metodo*/
    }
}

class B extends A{

}
```

Quando eu fizer:

```
System.out.println(A.getClass()); // deve mostrar "A"
System.out.println(B.getClass()); // deve mostrar "B"
```

Comment: Até onde eu saiba, isso não é possível. Tanto métodos estáticos quanto de instância são herdados pelas subclasses, mas [seu comportamento é um tanto diferente](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html). No meu entendimento, ainda que [a JVM invoque os métodos de maneira diferente no bytecode](http://pastebin.com/zfW4pH7U) (P.S. usei `getClass2` para não dar erro), uma vez que que o mesmo é despachado (*dispatched*) creio que a informação sobre a chamada original se perca. Mas posso estar enganado, é bom esperar a resposta de alguém que entenda melhor do assunto.

Answer (score 4):

Não acredito que seja possível obter o nome da classe base via reflexão quando essa classe é estática. Será necessário ter uma referencia direta para a classe que deseja saber o nome. Isso acontece por que em java, quando as assinaturas dos métodos da base e deriva colidem, a derivada não sobrescreve o método, acontece algo chamado *hide* (veja um exemplo [aqui](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)).

De acordo com o paradigma orientado a objetos, é necessário existir uma instância para que ocorra a sobrecarga. Nesse caso, temos [métodos estáticos](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9todo_%28programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29#M.C3.A9todos_est.C3.A1ticos), que pertencem a classe e não a uma instância. Esses método são resolvidos em tempo de compilação e não dinamicamente (em tempo de execução), como acontecem com os métodos de instâncias. Assim, o polimorfismo que estamos acostumados não existe no contexto estático.

Levando em conta o seu exemplo, se fizermos:

```
class A {
    public static String getNome(){
        return A.class.getSimpleName();
    }
}

class B extends A {
}

System.out.println(A.getNome()); // vai mostra "A"
System.out.println(B.getNome()); // vai mostrar "A"
```

Uma alteração nesse exemplo para chegar próximo do que queremos seria:

```
class A {
    public static String getNome(){
        return A.class.getSimpleName();
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public static String getNome(){
        return B.class.getSimpleName();
    }
}

System.out.println(A.getNome()); // vai mostra "A"
System.out.println(B.getNome()); // vai mostrar "B"
```

Até aí tudo bem, é o comportamento esperado. Porém, quando não se utiliza um referência direta para o `B`, o problema volta a acontecer.

```
// mas o problema persiste quando não se utiliza um referência direta para o `B`
A x = new B();
System.out.println(x.getNome()); // vai mostrar "A"
```

**E se tentássemos analisando a *stack trace***

Quando analisada a *stack trace* das chamadas, não existe chamada para a classe B, quando não há referencia direta e "sobrecarga" do método `getNome()`, veja:

```
class A {
    public static String getNome(){
        String out = "";

        for (StackTraceElement var : Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()){
            out += var.getClassName() + "->";
        }

        out += ".";

       return out;
    }
}

class B extends A {
}

System.out.println(B.getNome());
// vai mostrar: java.lang.Thread->A->HelloWorld->.
```

Mesmo com a referencia para `B`, não há registro na *stack trace*. O mesmo acontece para:

```
System.out.println(A.getNome());
// vai mostrar: java.lang.Thread->A->HelloWorld->.
```

e, mesmo "sobrecarregando" o método em `B`, o comportamento esperado não acontece:

```
class B extends A {
    // Agora "sobrecarregando" o método getNome()
    public static String getNome(){
        return A.getNome();
    }
}

System.out.println(B.getNome());
// vai mostrar: java.lang.Thread->A->HelloWorld->.
```

Parafraseando os matemático: logo, fica "demonstrado", que não é possível obter o nome da classe "chamadora" utilizando polimorfirmo e reflexão sem um referência direta para a classe "chamadora".

Nessa caso, ter um referência direta para classe "chamadora" e implementar toda essa parafernalha é um absurdo! Se você tem a referência do que quer saber o nome use `B.class.getSimpleName()` ou `A.class.getSimpleName()`. Se já tem tudo em tempo de compilação, não precisa resolver em tempo de execução (dinamicamente) :)

Answer (score 2):

stack.**Principal**

```
package stack;

public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Dinâmico
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        a.getClasse();
        b.getClasse();
        //Estático
        A.getStaticClasse();
        B.getStaticClasse();
    }
}
```

stack.**A**

```
public  class A {
       public void getClasse(){
               System.out.println("classe = " + this.getClass());
       }
       
       public static void getStaticClasse(){
               System.out.println("classe estatica = " + A.class.getName());
       }
}
```

stack.**B**

```
package stack;

public class B extends A{
    public static void getStaticClasse(){
           System.out.println("class estática= " + B.class.getName());
   }
}
```

Saída:

```
class = class stack.A
class = class stack.B
static class = stack.A
static class = stack.B
```

Caso queira baixar o projeto o mesmo se encontra no [GitHub](https://github.com/kyllopardiun/StackOverflow/tree/master/Respostas/StackOverflow22135)

Note que terá que criar tal método em todas as classes, ou o retorno continuaria sendo `stack.A`.

Comment: Embora isso esteja correto, não responde ao que foi perguntado. (no seu código o contexto é dinâmico, não estático)

Comment: @mgibsonbr, obrigado pelo aviso. Já corrigi a resposta.